# How to convert Html to String in Android Java?

Tags: java, android

I have Html format like this :

```
"<div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\">\n
    <a href=\"https://i.pinimg.com/564x/c1/8e/21/c18e214e1dbd100a51d3256d080548cb.jpg\" 
        imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img border=\"0\" 
        data-original-height=\"800\" data-original-width=\"552\" 
        src=\"https://i.pinimg.com/564x/c1/8e/21/c18e214e1dbd100a51d3256d080548cb.jpg\" />
    </a>
</div>\n<br />"
```

How to get `https://i.pinimg.com/564x/c1/8e/21/c18e214e1dbd100a51d3256d080548cb.jpg` from Html `src` above and convert to String? I want to display an image from URL then i put to Glide ImageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html is not a regular language, so it cant be parsed using regular expressions.
But there is a special tools for it, i prefer `Jsoup` library.
So, here is snippet

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
//other dependencies
implementation "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1" }
```

Link extracting

```
  val text = "<div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\">" +
"<a href=\"https://i.pinimg.com/564x/c1/8e/21/c18e214e1dbd100a51d3256d080548cb.jpg\""+
"imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"><img border=\"0\""+
"data-original-height=\"800\" data-original-width=\"552\""+
"src=\"https://i.pinimg.com/564x/c1/8e/21/c18e214e1dbd100a51d3256d080548cb.jpg\" />"+
"</a>"+
"</div>\n<br />"
val doc = Jsoup.parse(text)
val link = doc.select(".separator a").attr("href").toString()
print(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the html and search for the first appearance of the word "src". Afterwards move to the first '"' and add each character to an array/list until character equals '"' again.

Edit: Instead of iterating through the whole thing you can also get the position of the src occurence with indexOf() and iterate from this position as mentioned above.